# How can I see answered set of questions?

Tags: support, questions

Usually I can see Unanswered tab in the StackOverflow so that I can see the list of Unanswered Questions. But, I was wondering if there is any way/trick to see the list of questions that are already answered?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: Only to see the already answered questions (For better analysis of answers and questions)

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you mean by *answered*.

- If you mean questions with accepted answers, then yes, you can.

  Search using `hasaccepted:yes` -> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ayes
- If you want to search for questions with a certain number of answers, then search using `answers:<number>`. This will return questions having `<number>` or more answers